# Need help with a math trick question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

I wasnt sure where to ask this but since this is an algorithmic question here it goes. I've come face to face with a math problem and can't seem to get over it for the last couple of days. It goes like this:

> You are given an adding machine that sums a set of N+1 digits
>   consisting of positive integers 1 to N
>   as it's given the numbers (e.g. the
>   machine is given 3 as the first number
>   and outputs 3. It's then given 6 as
>   the second number and outputs 9. It's
>   given 11 as the third number and
>   outputs 20. Etcetera until it has
>   processed N+1 numbers). One (and only
>   one) of the digits is repeated. How do
>   you determine which number is
>   repeated?

It seems like a trick question and I'd be really pissed off it is just that a question to which the answer is 'not possible' - any ideas here?

Comment: Why use the word digit at all?

Answer (score 6):

We know that $1+2+\ldots +N = \frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$. Suppose the end amount is $T$ then the repeated number is $T-\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$.

Comment: WHat is this branch of mathematics called btw?

Comment: The numbers of the form $\frac{1}{2}N(N+1)$ are triangle numbers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: @Ali: I would say it falls under arithmetic. Lookup Arithmetic Progressions on the web.